# soldering input pins to SN74HC595N shift register -- heat tolerance

Tags: heat, tolerance

I'm working on a project that uses the [SN74HC595N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf) shift register from TI. The nature of this project requires that I solder on pin extensions. My soldering skills are not too solid, so I'm worried that I may be damaging it (based on it's performance, I'm pretty sure that I am).

I know that the operational temperature is -40°C ~ 85°C

My question. How hot can this shift register get before it sustains permanent damage. And is improper soldering the likely cause of the shift register's malfunction as I presume?

Comment: If you are really worried about your soldering skills, then practice a little bit. At the point where you need less than 2 seconds for a solder joint there should not be any problem.

Comment: Breaking the rules means the result is without any process certification, but it's actually pretty rare to damage ICs by overheating with a soldering iron.  If it is behaving oddly, have you considering clock glitches?  What are you clocking it with?

Answer (score 3):

150C is the maximum storage temperature, according to the data sheet. If you keep it below that you should be OK. It shouldn't get that hot with proper soldering techniques.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure of what "pin extensions" is, but, generally, you should be using sockets for all your ICs up until production run. Advantages include:

- while soldering, you heat the socket, not the IC
- if/when the IC burns out or is damaged otherwise, it takes 5 seconds to replace it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this chip in particular, but I have heated PIC's with multiple cycles of 500°C for up to 2 minutes, with no sign of damage...

Answer (score -2):

when I'm soldering that kind of things, I normally connect a crocodile clip to the pin on other side of the pcb. So that clip will work as a heat sink and absorb heat and avoid
damaging the component.

EDIT: Either you use a crocrodile clip or use a precise dynamic heat controlled soldering
iron, there still a chance that you damage the chip due to ESD. So soldering it is not
a good idea in a DIY environment.

Comment: So if soldering in DIY environment is not a good idea, when exactly is soldering a good idea? Heatsinking a pin seems to be the exact opposite logic to thermal reliefs being created at PCB pads, to prevent the heat during soldering from being conducted away.

Comment: I have been given this advice also. Hold the pin, next to the chip body with pliers while soldering, to protect the silicone. I have never used it, though, multiple resolders never damaged anything for me.